# Why do Python standard library modules not follow basic PEP8 rules?

Tags: python

I was looking through source code for some Python modules and I noticed **lots** of instances where PEP8 isn't followed and there's no obvious reason (at least to me) that it shouldn't have been. I'm totally aware that there are times when strictly adhering to a PEP8 rule isn't the best option, but I don't see it in these cases. Here's a small example taken from [here in the logging library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2b5913b4ee5852a28ca1509478f5582beb3aff7b/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L326) of where it seems like they should use snake_case.

```
    self.funcName = func
    self.created = ct
    self.msecs = (ct - int(ct)) * 1000
    self.relativeCreated = (self.created - _startTime) * 1000
```

They use mostly camelCase in this module but have other exceptions like `def _showwarning`, which also seems odd to me. I know [this question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148707/python-core-library-and-pep8), but I don't see how those answers apply to something as simple as switching to snake_case. But being that Python is widely popular and been around for a long time, I'm guessing I'm missing something. What am I missing?

Comment: I would say that PEP8 was either created after those libraries or was not followed as much at the time, it is also not mandatory to follow

Comment: I get that it's not mandatory and up to the implementers, but isn't there a belief that the recommendations are worthwhile enough to be worth refactoring code to follow it? To me, not having it follow PEP8 suggests that even some core Python maintainers don't believe the PEP8 conventions are valuable enough to refactor old code.

Comment: did You not read other reasons? the code may have been made prior to PEP8 so there was nothing expected

Comment: Yes, I did. I was thinking about refactoring *after* PEP* had been adopted.

Comment: what would be the point of that? imagine rewriting thousands of lines just to match code styling convention, there is no point especially if the code works also You don't see that code often, therefore it shouldn't bother You from a visual appeal

Answer (score 3):

Please read the answers again: the salient points are clear to me.

1. There are no PEP8 **rules**.  PEP is a set of conventions and recommendations.  When to follow them at all, and how closely, is up to the developer.
2. Many projects pre-date PEP8, or were executed close enough that those naming practices were not as widespread.  In some cases, local professional standards would have more influence than PEP.  I've worked in groups that *still* do camelCase for standard variables.
3. Coding standards for implementation are up to the implementers.  There is no textual review by any Python oversight committee.  So long as the vendor's implementation meets the Python language standards -- that's functionality, *not* coding style -- the interpreter is valid Python.

Comment: It should be noted that PEP8 itself explicitly includes exceptions for code written before PEP8's own introduction. It should also be noted that PEP8 was written as a style guide *for the developers*; widespread adoption in the community is just a bonus.